# Show that $\frac{a^x-1}{x}\to\log(a)$ monotonically as $x\searrow0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, inequality

**Problem:** Fix $a>0$. Consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{a^x-1}{x}\quad\text{for }x>0.$$
Prove that $f(x)\searrow\log(a)$ as $x\searrow0$.

**My Thoughts:** The calculation of the limit follows from L'Hopital's rule. Set $\varphi(x)=a^x-1$ and $\psi(x)=x$ for $x\in\mathbb R$. Then $\varphi(x),\psi(x)\to0$ as $x\to0$. Since $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are differentiable on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, we have
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\varphi(x)}{\psi(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\varphi'(x)}{\psi'(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a^x\log(a)}{1}=\log(a).$$
The hard part, for me at least, is to show that function decreases monotonically toward the limit. I try with the mean value theorem. Since we take the limit as $p\searrow0$ it suffices to consider $0<x<y<1$. Then by the mean value theorem, there is some $c\in(x,y)$ such that
$$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=f'(c),$$
and in particular, if we can show that $f'(c)\geq0$, then we are done. First, consider $0<a\leq1$. Then using the fact that $1-1/x\leq\log(x)$ for $0<x\leq1$, we see that
$$f'(c)=\frac{ca^c\log(a)-a^c+1}{x^2}\geq0,$$
since $1-1/a^c\leq\log(a^c).$ So the result holds for $0<a\leq1$.

However, I have not been able to prove the analogous result for the case $a>1$, which does seem to hold when graphing a few examples.

---

Could anyone please help me out with a hint on how to approach the case $a>1$?
Thank you very much for your help and appreciate any feedback on the part of the problem that I think I could approach successfully.

Comment: Note that the limit is a derivative.

Comment: Series expansion of $a^{x}=e^{x \ln a}$ shows that the function is increasing in $x$ for $a>1$. This means it decreases as $x$ decreases to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi(x):=a^x=e^{x\log a}$

The limit you are after is $\phi'(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}$

Assuming $a>0$,  $\phi$ is convex: $\phi''(x)=(\log a)^2a^x>0$.

Recall that a function  $\varphi:(\alpha,\beta)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
$-\infty\leq \alpha<\beta\leq \infty$, is convex if
$$\begin{align}
\varphi((1-t) x+ t y)\leq (1-t)\varphi(x)+t \varphi(y)\tag{1}\label{convex}
\end{align}$$
for any $\alpha<x<y<\beta$ and $0\leq t\leq 1$. If strict inequality holds
in $\eqref{convex}$ with $0<t<1$, then $\varphi$ is strictly convex.

Geometrically, if $\varphi$ is convex and $\alpha<x<u<y<\beta$ then the point
$(u,\varphi(u))$ on the graph of $\varphi$ lies below the straight line
joining  $(x,\varphi(x))$ and $(y,\varphi(y))$. Let   $u=(1-t)x+ty$,
It is easy to check that
$\eqref{convex}$ is equivalent to any of the inequalities
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\varphi(u)-\varphi(x)}{u-x}\leq\frac{\varphi(y)-\varphi(x)}{y-x}\leq 
\frac{\varphi(y)-\varphi(u)}{y-u}\tag{2}\label{convex-equiv}
\end{align}
$$
For fixed  $\alpha<x<\beta$, inequalities~\eqref{convex-equiv} show that the map
$u\mapsto \tfrac{\varphi(u)-\varphi(x)}{u-x}$
decreases as $u\searrow x$  and  increases as $u\nearrow x$.

In your case

$$
\frac 1x (a^{x}-1)=\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x-0}
$$